# Какую кодировку выбрать в PMA если там нет обычной utf8

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

какую кодировку выбрать в PMA если там нет обычной utf8? Один раз я выбрал странную кодировку и русские буквы не отображались. В этот раз хотелось бы избежать этого.

[image: Пхп]

Comment: Utf-8 mb4 как вариант

Comment: @こきん utf8_bin подойдёт?

Comment: Я и utf-8 mb4 тоже попробую

Comment: Вы можете самостоятельно прочитать в чем их разница.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utf8_general_ci вот это должно легко сработать